Does a Chad citizen need a transit visa in Brazil?
I am a Chadian citizen, and I booked a ticket to Suriname. The itinerary is Windhoek - Luanda - Sao Paulo - Belem - Paramaribo. Do I need a Brazilian visa Transit?

Since you have a Brazilian domestic flight in there, you almost certainly do.

It depends, in Brazil some "domestic" flights have a short stop in a domestic destination before going abroad, those flights depart from international terminals.

Are all these flights on the same ticket?

It’s a Kiwi route with two self-transfers and a domestic flight in Brazil. You will need a full visa to enter Brazil (transit visas no longer exist).

You most likely need a visa and since you are passing by Luanda you probably need a yellow fever vaccination as well.
The only possible visa exception is if you are staying in the international area of Guarulhos airport in Sāo Paulo for 7 hours or less.

In case you change planes in Belém you will need to transit from international to domestic areas in Sāo Paulo and a visa is required.
In case you travel on the same plane from Sāo Paulo to Paramaribo, you aren't leaving the plane in Belém AND your layover in Sāo Paulo is shorter than 7 hours you don't need a visa.


While a theoretical possibility, this seems highly unlikely on that route. GOL do have aircraft flying São Paulo - Brasilia - Belem - Paramaribo but they are 3 different flights, two of which are domestic.

If the passengers bound to Paramaribo are not leaving the plane in Brasília and Belém this plane will depart from international terminals not only in Belém, but also in Brasília and São Paulo. This is a possibility, depends on how the flight is organized, I don't think it happens on this route though.

They are 3 different flights, with passengers doing any of the three flights as they want, so the first two are clearly domestic flights. Given the extremely low traffic to Paramaribo, there is about 0 chance that there will be an international flight to there with an intermediate stop in Brazil.
